# Should I deploy my Nuxt app directly to Google App Engine or should I use Gitlab CI/CD where my code is present in repository?

Tags: node.js, git, google-app-engine, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy my nuxt app to App Engine. And I am confused which method I should go for.
I have tried deploying directly using `gcloud app deploy` command. It works. But when I make changes and deploy again it makes another version of my project in app engine. And I guess all the files are uploaded again instead of files modified or newly created. Correct me if I am wrong about this.

Or should I go for Gitlab CI and link my master branch with app engine so whenever I make changes in Gitlab the changes gets automatically reflected.

I want to know if Gitlab also makes new version of app whenever it is updated.

Comment: `gcloud app deploy --help` will answer the first part of your question.

Comment: Thank You for answering. I directly deployed to App Engine and updating the app is also very easy. So it's working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both alternatives will be creating a new version.

This allows that the changes can be rolled back in an easier way in case something breaks your application.

Comment: Thank You for answering. I directly deployed to App Engine and updating the app is also very easy. So it's working as it should.

Comment: Hi Shubhang, if the answer worked for you please accept the answer